# Is there a way to see how many questions have been answered in a specific tag?

Tags: support, tags

I'm comparing several IDE's for Android development and I want to take into that comparison how often questions are asked about them and how many of those have been answered, so that I can see from what other sources I might get help if I decide to use one of those.

The IDE's in question are Android Studio, Delphi XE7, Qt and Xamarin.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-studio%20or%20delphi%20or%20qt%20or%20xamarin Looks like 84,499 for the bunch.

Comment: But where can I see how many of those questions have been answered?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-studio+or+delphi+or+qt+or+xamarin?sort=unanswered&pageSize=50  20,348 unanswered questions tagged

Comment: Okay, I can subtract those from the total questions. But, isn't there a way to see how many questions in a tag are answered?

Comment: I mean like a 1000 questions/900 answered, something like that.

Comment: There may be another way, but, what's wrong with subtraction? 64151. Now you have all the elements necessary for your little ratio.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with subtraction, it's just easier if it's already displayed somewhere.

Comment: You could make an [SQL query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries) if you really wanted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can always just [run a query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/286764/tag-question-answer-counts).

It *should* be pretty obvious to see how to modify the query for other tags.

According to that query, [qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qt) is the most popular... but I'm not sure if this is actually the specific tag you're looking for.  It's massively out in front.  It's also got a significant edge in terms of percentage answered and answer accepted.

After [qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qt), though, the other three all have similar numbers in terms of percentage answered, with [android-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-studio) being the most popular of the bunch.

Importantly, this query gives us some different stats from Bill the Lizard's proposed method.  You should understand the differences before choosing which method you prefer.

On Stack Exchange websites, a question is considered unanswered until it has an answer which has a positive score or an answer marked accepted.  The query I've linked here doesn't make that consideration, so a question with 4 answers all with negative votes, will count as answered in my query, but unanswered via Bill's method (the query could easily be modified to work this way... or to provide both results in side-by-side columns).

Ultimately, using the Stack Exchange Data Explorer, you can find out any information you like.  It's particularly helpful for these sorts of queries.  You can much more easily get several useful stats all in a nice neat little grid that makes it much easier to look at.

Answer (score 11):

If you click on any tag there's a "top users" link near the top of the page (in the box that explains what the tag is about).  Click on that and you can see the [unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered) percentage for questions in that tag. For example, for [Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/android-studio/topusers) you can see that 39.7% of questions asked are currently unanswered.

Comment: That's... a very intuitive place, actually. </sarcasm> _Why is it there?_

Comment: @JanDvorak That's a good question. There should probably be a separate "tag stats" tab on that page instead of shoe-horning that information into the top users tab.

Comment: It's there so when the top users come to see how much they've done, they're reminded of how much more there is to do.  (More seriously, if we have a "tag stats" page, what other stats would be interesting?)

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom The % closed and deleted might help us spot bad tags. The number of bounties (currently open and all-time) would be nice to see too.

Comment: *smells feature-request*